# How to force change background of UIWebView using javascript?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

This is what I've tried so far, nothing works:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function changeBackground(color) { document.body.style.background = color;}<BODY onload=\"changeBackground('red');\">"];

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"chageBackground(red);"];
```

Any ideas? Help? Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.background ='red';"];
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @WMios, I have changed answer

Comment: Guys, im sooo embarrassed right now.... I never noticed that im calling this function wrong... My code is good, but i have a typo when calling changeBackground(red); javaScript... I typed chageBackground.... My mistake im so sorry for spamming like this...